# Can't update wordpress hosted in openshift php app

Tags: wordpress, openshift

When I click on `update now` button show me follow output:
My webhost is openshift (php 5.3 not wordpress) app

```
Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-4.0.1-no-content.zip…

Unpacking the update…

Verifying the unpacked files…

Preparing to install the latest version…

Enabling Maintenance mode…

Copying the required files…

Disabling Maintenance mode…

Upgrading database…

WordPress updated successfully

Welcome to WordPress 4.0.1. You will be redirected to the About WordPress screen. If not, click here.
```

But after all nothing changed and show `Welcome to WordPress 3.9.2`
Please tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop & start your application for the upgrade to show up.  Not a restart, a stop and start.

Comment: How can this be done? there is only a 'restart application' button on RH OpenShift ..?!

Comment: Use the rhc tools, rhc app stop, rhc app start